# Why is there no output when I use a float conversion specifier in C

Tags: c, conversion-specifier

I wrote the code below for a lab assignment, but the output isn't what I expect. There are no errors, but the formatted float doesn't show up. May someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My code:

```
    /*Include files */
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>     

int main(void){    

    char patients[] = {'A', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'};
    float edvValues[] = {118.0, 120.0, 119.0, 122.0, 124.0, 121.0}; // Units of mL
    float esvValues[] = {48.0, 55.0, 52.0, 53.0, 50.0, 51.0}; // Units of mL
    float heartRateValues[] = {62.0, 80.0, 65.0, 70.0, 66.0, 64.0};
    
    for(int j = 0; j < sizeof(patients); j++){
            printf("Patient %c: ", patients[j]);
            printf("SV %d", (int)(edvValues[j] - esvValues[j]));
            printf(" CO %f L/min\n\r", (edvValues[j] - esvValues[j]) * heartRateValues[j]);
        }
    while(1);
}
```

And here's the expected output:

[image: correct output]

And here's my output:

[image: partially completed code that leaves out the area where the formatted float number should be]

Comment: What compiler and environment?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show the full program (`main`, includes, etc) to remove any ambiguity as a [mcve]. What is the expected output, exactly and what output are you getting?

Comment: You don't need to print a `\r` - the `\n` will translate to `\r\n` automatically on text-based streams on OS that need it (like Windows)

Comment: It works for me, so it must be code you haven't shown: https://onlinegdb.com/rkXzcgyHP

Comment: Correct output has `"mL"`, unlike this code.  Why not at least match that?

Comment: @dxiv I'm using Keil IDE with Tera Term to display output. The code I'm writing is loaded onto a TI microcontroller.

Comment: @user13316497 Check your library docs. It is possible that the `printf` implementation does not support floating point, or may require some special setting to enable.

Comment: Try removing the `\r` in the last `printf`.

Comment: The correct sequence is `\r\n` and not `\n\r` if you really need the `\r`